# Returning a result dependent upon a combination of inputs

Tags: algorithm, combinations, software-design

Consider a situation where we have a list containing some enumeration values and we must return a result that is dependent upon the combination of values present in this list. For example,

```
public enum Ingredient
{
  Meat,
  Vegetables,
  Broth
}

//...
public int extraIngredients;
public Dish GetDish(List<Ingredient> ingredients);
```

In this example, we want the following behavior from `GetDish()`:

{Meat} => `new Steak()`

{Meat, Meat} => `new Steak(); extraIngredients++`

{Meat, Vegetables} => `new StirFry()`

{Meat, Meat, Vegetables, Vegetables} => `new StirFry(); extraIngredients += 2`

{Meat, Vegetables, Broth} => `new Stew()`

{Broth} => `new Soup()`

etc, etc.

We want the solution to be extensible in case new `Ingredient`s are introduced in the future.

Essentially, every unique combination (NOT permutation) of `Ingredient`s produces a unique `Dish`. Any duplicate `Ingredient`s in the list triggers some defined side-effect. Does anyone have a lead on a clean solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: Lexically sort the enumerated values, join the sorted list into a key.

Comment: @danh You have me at "Lexically sort the enumerated values", but you lost me at "join the sorted list into a key".

Comment: I think pattern matching can help you solve your case, if all the combinations you need are known.

Comment: @AldenBernitt, I mean join, like a JavaScript join to convert the sorted array into a symbolic key.

Comment: @danh I'm following you now. There is just the difficulty of the defining the side-effect now.

Comment: You are right, my sum approach fails. What about creating various RequiredIngredientsList<Ingredient>, then asking the user to enter a List of <Ingredient>, and checking if any of the existing lists contain every element entered by the user?